# How to type narrow array types passed in functions?

Tags: typescript

I want to do type narrowing when working with array types but union members aren't getting distinguished. It is weird that they work in the first function `print1()` which is without arrays but doesn't work in the second function `print2()`.

```js
type Point = {
  x: number;
  y:number;
}
type Pair = [number, number]

type Coords = Point | Pair

function print1(a: Coords): number{
  if("x" in a){
    return a.x;
  } else{
    return a[0];
  }
}

function print2(a: Pair[] | Point[]): void{
  if("x" in a[0]){
    console.log(a[0].x)
  } else{
    console.log(a[0][0])
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: However, the type of `a[0]` is [correctly narrowed down to `Pair`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gSwHbCgXigbwLACgpQAeAXFEgK4C2ARhAE4DceBIpFN9TuAvnqJLACGCOuigBtdrToAaMlWkBdPH3DQAwnDh0AJgGcx8ZKgA+QkStwAzckgDGwBHCRQwdYwEYAFINKbt+gCUbAr0OPhQCFZeAESEMZEugoFYzARQdBDA5HRJAHSEXATcUBAANnrQ4ekZWTlJ4gAMikVQvDyWNvaOzq7uKABMPqQwwnTiilBmRigTwVAAbog61ZHRcQnIUIJNiimrBHbOenBlEHllcADmPrsFgWkl5ZWpEYfHqNQjY2I7za3vJAnM4Xa5eai7B4RdrcIA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's interesting that it successfully narrows `a[0]` but not `a[1]` or the whole array, even though narrowing `a[0]` can also narrow the rest of the array. You could consider [reporting it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) if nobody hasn't already.

Until then, you can "fix" this with a simple [type guard/predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
const isPairArray = (arr: Pair[] | Point[]): arr is Pair[] => arr[0] && 'x' in arr[0];

function print2(a: Pair[] | Point[]): void {
    if (isPairArray(a)) {
        console.log(a[0][0])
    } else {
        console.log(a[0].x)
    }
}
```

In that case, `a` is properly narrowed to either `Pair[]` or `Point[]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "limitation" with TypeScript (its actually a great feature of typescript, since JavaScript is the real culprit here). According to typescript `a[0]` in the expression `'x' in a[0]` might not reference the same value as `a[0]` in the log statement `console.log(a[0].x)`.

In this case, storing `a[0]` in a variable will solve the issue.

```
function print2(a: Pair[] | Point[]): void{
  const b = a[0];
  if("x" in b){
    console.log(b.x)
  } else{
    console.log(b[0])
  }
}
```